# The alternative of .eof?

Tags: c++

Is there any alternative from using the .eof, by using cin as a condition for this?

```
while(cin.eof( )==false)
{
    cin >> number;
    sum += number;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. \`while (!stream.eof())\`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: You almost *never* want to use `.eof()`.

Comment: `while ( cin >> number )` then for any non number (assuming `number` is `double` or similar) it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better alternative:

```
while(cin >> number)
{
    sum += number;
    ++count;
}
```

See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/10147399)